# Hide html list item using css

Tags: html, css

I would like to remove (or make not visible) #tab4 from the end users view. I thought I could use something like

```
    #tab4 {
    visibilty: none;
    :
}
```

However thats not working. Do I need to target the ID as well?

---

```
<div id="tabs-widget-wrap">
                <ul id="tabs">
                    <li id=""><a href="#" name="#tab1" id="">Description</a></li>
                    <li id=""><a href="#" name="#tab2" id="">Features</a></li>              
                    <li id="current"><a href="#" name="#tab3" id="current">Policies</a></li>    
                    <li id=""><a href="#" name="#tab4" id="">Availability</a></li>
                    <li id=""><a href="#" name="#tab5" id="">Review (0) </a></li>
                </ul>
```

Comment: you have the same id twice in the page. it's not legal.

Comment: `none` isn't a valid value for the `visibility` property. Try either `hidden` or `visible`

Comment: I don't understand why my answer was marked negative.The person who did this will you explain why ?? because the question is about to hide list item by css  he mentioned  #tab4.I write css and hide #tab4 named item.   I answered it using css    So why ?????

Comment: As @avrahamcool suggested, you're misusing `id` - what you have would be better as classes ...`<li class="tab">` and the active one `<li class="tab active">`. If you _really_ want an `id` on each tab they must be unique. Sensible ones could be `id="desc"`, `id="features"` etc. But many people use ids where classes would do a better job. e.g. If you had more than one tab-set a tab _set_ might have an id, not the tabs. `<div class="tabs-widget-wrap" id="tab-set-1">`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello just use the below css to hide #tab4

```
   #tabs-widget-wrap ul li:nth-child(4)
   {
   display: none;
   }
```

:nth-child(4) it allows you to specifically choose to change only the 4th element in the parent element. Here #tab4 is your 4th element

Comment: @Dano007 - I am not the downvoter, just making a guess as to why it was downvoted ... it could be because it does not explain how & why it works. Stackoverflow considers "good" questions and _answers_ as ones that will help people in the future, not just the original poster. This solves your problem but doesn't teach you anything, and probably wouldn't help some future person with a very similar but not exactly the same issue. The tooltip on downvote is "This answer is not useful" and some people will downvote based on its lack of future usefulness.

Answer (score 2):

```
<li id="tab4"><a href="#">Availability</a></li>
```

CSS:

```
#tab4 {
    display: none;
}
```

jQuery:

```
$('#tab4').hide();
```

Inline HTML:

```
<li style="display:none;"><a href="#">Availability</a></li>
```

Comment: Your ID has a `#` in it.

Answer (score 1):

```
#tab4 {
    display: none;
}

This should work
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no property `visibility:none;` it's `visibility:hidden;`

In addition, you have no id of `tab4` for that element. It should be 
`id="tab4"` Putting that into the attribute `name` won't do it.

Answer (score -1):

You try to select by `name` property.

```
a[name="#tab4"] {
    visibility: none;
}
```